# How do you apply shadows to controls in xaml for Windows 8(RT)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I see that most of the WPF stuff use for example DropShadowEffect, but my xaml in WinRT doesn't recognize that, is there something else to use?

Answer (score 3):

However it's easy to add dropshadow to text. As photoshop dude I immediately released this:

```
<Grid>
<TextBlock Margin="1,1,0,0" Foreground="<!--Shadow Color-->" Text="Some text"/>
<TextBlock Foreground="<!--Text Color-->" Text="Some text"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the DropShadowEffect is not available in Windows Store apps.

For now, effects are programmed with DirectX and C++.  If you don't want to write your own interop library in C++, check out the [sharpdx.org/ library](http://sharpdx.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Shape of the Control you could create an Image (.png e.g.) with a dropshadow effect towards the outer bounds and include it in the style of the control with the help of Nine-Grid ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189722.aspx )

(if the dropshadow is 5px wide you can set the margin to -5 and the nine-grid values to 5 to make the shadow appear around the control)

Greetings

Answer (score -3):

You can use `DropShadowBitmapEffect` to create Shadow effect.

The documentation and an example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms753350(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Bitmap effects are not available for Metro applications

Comment: I have seen somebody add shadows to some control that looks like a panel in WinRT, so it must be possible?

Comment: Effects are possible, through other means, but the BitMapEffect and Effect classes found in WPF are not in the WinRT API.

Comment: Sadly Effects are not available in Windows Apps.